# Is it possible to send mail using OAuth for GMail

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, gmail

I want to send mail from user gmail account using OAuth to all user contacts.

It's easy to get all contacts of user with google API, but i cant send email to these contacts from user gmail account without request his password.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution on this? I have the exact goal, sending email via gmail / yahoo / hotmail to a users selected contacts using Oauth to login. The page linked below (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_protocol#smtp) seems absurdly complicated. It seems to require raw communication with the SMTP server?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

> The protocol allowing for an application to access IMAP and SMTP using OAuth is based on the Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL) and the native IMAP AUTHENTICATE and SMTP AUTH commands.

Since you can use SMTP via OAuth, you can send mail.

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/

Comment: i'v seen this link, but cant find params for sending email for request (https://mail.google.com/mail/b/<email address>/smtp/)

Comment: You send the mail with SMTP, not by stuffing it in an HTTP URI. There is an example one click away from the page I linked to: http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html#smtp

Comment: Can i do this: App(js,css,html) that can send emails via users gmail while not being a gadget, so it's on its own site myappmail.cometc...Also get contact list to provide contacts fast. And confirm if the email was sent. Is there such a way with gmail api. Thanks a lot in advance. :D